# IntelliJ IDEA and PHP inheritance

Tags: php, intellij-idea

I am running into trouble making IntelliJ IDEA display inherited methods correctly.

I have an abstract *BaseController* class holding two protected field variables (f3 and db). In the extending *ForumController* class, **db** works fine, but the static **f3** does not (see screenshots below).

The framework used is FatFree, if that helps.

[image: abstract BaseController]
[image: extending ForumController]

Any help or suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the tags of [phpdoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHPDoc) to document all classes, properties and methods. IntelliJ uses those to determine what possible values a property or variable may hold. In this case documenting the `$f3` property could be sufficient:

```
/**
 * @var Base
 */
protected $f3;
```

After typing the first `/**` on the line before the property and pressing enter IntelliJ will generate a docblock for you with what it knows already.

Comment: That totally did it! Thank you so very much!

Answer (score 0):

In fatfree framework, the instance of Base class ($f3 in your code) is passed to the constructor, so you can use type hinting there:

```
public function __construct(Base $f3){
    $this->f3 = $f3;
```

Though retrieving the instance from the registry via the static call `Base::instance();` and using phpdoc comments as in the accepted answer is fine as well.